# Polynomial ring over direct product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\{R_1, R_2, \dots, R_n \}$ be a class of rings. Is $(\prod_{i=1}^{n}R_i)[x] \cong \prod_{i=1}^{n} R_i[x]$?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to show the case $n=2$ since the more general result follows by induction. Let $A$ and $B$ be rings.

Define $f: (A \times B)[x] \to A[x] \times B[x]$ by $f(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(a_i,b_i)x^i)=(\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_ix^i, \sum_{i=0}^{k}b_ix^i)$.

Can you show that this is indeed a bijective ring homomorphism and therefore an isomorphism?